# DOM javascript- add all elements as selected

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working with DOM and when I press the key "i" all elements should get the class "selected".

I cannot see why the piece of code that I have written is not working, please help me.

My idea is to gather a list of all elements that does not have class selcted in "nodeList". Once I have that, I loop through nodelist and to each element I add the class "selected". In the end I want to console.log how many elements are selected. However, no part of this code works! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
if(keyCode === 105) {
        nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("not(.selected)");
        for(i= 0; i< nodeList.length; i++) {
             place = nodeList[i];
             place.classList.add("selected");            
        }
        nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(.selected);
        console.log(nodeList.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem the use of [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), it is a [pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), you have used it as an element selector(with wrong syntax)

```
if (keyCode === 105) {
    nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.selected)");//it is a pseudo selector
    for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        place = nodeList[i];
        place.classList.add("selected");
    }
    nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');//also use string literal here
    console.log(nodeList.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked better now, however I have gotten a new problem. Now it adds the class "selected" to all elements including body, title and the script. This is not how I intended to have it. How do I write the code so I remove these three classes?

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll("body :not(.selected):not(script)");`

Answer (score 1):

`not(.selected)` should be `:not(.selected)`